# Lightdm display manager timeout error

Tags: lightdm

In Ubuntu 18.04 using `lightdm` as a display-manager, but the status of the `lightdm` service is always activating and exactly at 90 Sec after service get started it was showing `status=activating` and session timeout and GUI screen is refreshing going back to login page

`lightdm` service:

```
systemctl status lightdm.service[FAILED] Failed to start Light Display Manager.
See 'systemctl status lightdm.service' for details.
```

Comment: Please be aware that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which was released in 2018-April (thus the 18.04) had 5 years of *standard* support life, is nearing the end of those five years.  As such, if the machine is on-line, you should plan to *release-upgrade* asap unless you plan to use ESM, but please note ESM releases are not on-topic here when standard support ends.

Comment: You might want to start by looking at the journal for pertinent error messages ex. `journalctl -xe -u lightdm`